# Any other better logic for this programme

Tags: php, logic

Today in an interview i got the following question to solve without using any inbuilt function eg in_array and etc.I am able to solve the programme but they told me is there any better approach and also they told me the total code is only upto 7 lines.So can anyone tell me any better approach than this:-

```
<?php
$a = array(1,3,5,2,1,5,11,16);
$b = array(1,4,3,11,12,5,7,18);
$final = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
    $flag = 0;
    if($i==0){
        $final[] = $a[$i];
    } else {
        for($j=0;$j<count($final);$j++){

            if($a[$i] == $final[$j]){
                $flag = 1;
            }

        }
        if($flag==0){
            $final[] = $a[$i];
        }
        for($k=0;$k<count($final);$k++){
            if($b[$i] == $final[$k]){
                $flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if($flag==0){
            $final[] = $b[$i];
        }


    }

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
```

the result would be the final array which would contain unique array of both eg

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 2 [5] => 11 [6] => 16 [7] => 18 )
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: sorry, i updated my question,please check it now

Comment: The above is the code you did. And what was the initial code? only those two arrays? or three arrays?

Comment: Questions about improving working code belong on [codereview.se]

Comment: yes those two array was the question  and the result would be the final unique array of both

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do it without using built-in functions: Collect the values as keys (so they are unique), and then put those keys back as values in the final array:

```
$a = array(1,3,5,2,1,5,11,16);
$b = array(1,4,3,11,12,5,7,18);

foreach($a as $v) $keys[$v] = 1;
foreach($b as $v) $keys[$v] = 1;
foreach($keys as $k => $v) $final[] = $k;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/816986).

Comment: What did you expect? ;-)

Comment: I thought that the code would be more big but you did it in a short and efficient method

Answer (score 1):

Just set the key as the value and they will overwrite. If the arrays are the same length:

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    $final[$v] = $v;
    $final[$b[$k]] = $b[$k];
}
```

If not, then do it for each array:

```
foreach(array($a, $b) as $c) {
    foreach($c as $v) {
        $final[$v] = $v;
    }
}
```

The order and keys won't be the same, but that wasn't stated as a requirement.

Comment: Added another for different sizes.

Comment: The result here is an associative array, not a standard indexed array, where the first value would have key 0 as depicted in the OP's desired output. One could also object to the use of `array()`.

Comment: @trincot I know, but it's the easiest implementation to get _the final array which would contain unique array of both_.

Comment: but none of the above examples return the required format :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan e.g. means _for example_, not _required format_ ;-)